# java swing, highligth item in jcombobox popup

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

i want to highlight an item inside popup list.

I say "highlight" becouse i don't want to select it (for example by calling setSelectedItem) but only make it selected inside the jcombobox popup.

How can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sort of works in that an item other than the first is selected. However, if you use the keyboard to change selection, it always starts from the first because that is the one that is selected.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class ComboBoxSelect extends JFrame
{
    public ComboBoxSelect()
    {
        String[] items = { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5" };
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox( items );
        add( comboBox );

        comboBox.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener()
        {
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e)
            {
                JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
                BasicComboPopup popup = (BasicComboPopup)comboBox.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
                JList list = popup.getList();
                list.setSelectedIndex(2);
            }

            public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {}
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {}

        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ComboBoxSelect frame = new ComboBoxSelect();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This write-up provides guidance on how you could modify JComboBox:

- http://www.orbital-computer.de/JComboBox/

Although it's written for auto-complete functionality, a custom mechanism to highlight without selecting would be very similar (and probably easier).

Comment: This solution use setSelectedItem to highligth item in popup.